RSolve give a wrong result?
Bug introduced at or before 5.2, persisting through 14.1.

I am trying to solve the recurrence solution:
$$
a_{n+1}=a_{n}+2+2\sqrt{a_{n}} \tag1
$$
and the following is my Mathematica code:
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 2 + 2*Sqrt[a[n]], a[0] == 0}, a[n], n]

However, I've obtained the result
{{a[n] -> 2 n^2}}

When $n=0$, this is correct since the initial condition is, indeed, $a_{0}=0$. The value for $a_{1}$ is also correct
$$
a_{1}=a_{0}+2+2\sqrt{a_{0}}=2.
$$
However, when $n=2$, we have $2n^2=8$. On the other hand, by eq(1), we have
$$
a_{2}=a_{1}+2+2\sqrt{a_{1}}=4+2\sqrt{2}\ne 8.
$$
Is this a bug? Version for my Mathematica: 14.1.0

As a workaround, you can use ClearAll[a]; a[n_Integer?Positive] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + 2 + 2 Sqrt[a[n - 1]]; a[0] = 0; to compute a[n] for small n.

Note  n=2 not n=3. a[1]=1; a[2]= a[1]+2+2 Sqrt[a[1]= 2+2+2 Sqrt[2] = 4+2 Sqrt[2]  MMA is correct

Yes it is a bug. It should have returned the input as there is no closed form.

@DanielHuber Oh, thanks for noticing this. It's a typo. The result is still incorrect.

Am I the only one who sees this? Why your latex shows the index as exponent?  Should not $a^{n+1}$ be $a(n+1)$ in the latex? The way you wrote the latex now is very confusing for readers.

Yes this is a bug. I should report this to wolfram.

Version "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" returns {{a[n] -> 2 n^2}}. I agree this is a bug.  Adding the bugs tag.

An old bug, Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 produce the same {{a[n] -> 2 n^2}}.

@narip Are you using the current version of Mathematica? We should add a heading to the post indicating in what versions the bug appears, but I can't test past version 12.

@march Thank you for your comment. I use Mathematica version 14.1, as indicated by the output of $Version, which is 14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

AsymptoticRSolveValue gives the incorrect answer as well

See q/121756, 8 years ago

By the way, the corresponding ODE DSolve[f'[x] == 2 + 2 Sqrt[f[x]] && f[0] == 0, f[x], x]  Out: {{f[x] -> (1 + ProductLog[-E^(-1 - x)])^2}} works fine, as can be checked by solving the separable ODE using integration and Solve for inverting.
